How to repair/replace the wood relief on the outside of a french door?
I have a French door on the second floor balcony of my home. It has wood reliefs out the outside of the door that have been destroyed over time (we've had the house for 15 years), and are looking to get them replaced with hardy back or something that's a bit more weather resistant.
So I don't necessarily need a brand new door, but I do need the outside repairs done. Problem is, I don't know who I should inquire with to make it happen (handyman, door repair company, etc.) or to learn how to do it myself.
Does anyone have a recommendation on who I should talk to, or how to start this sort of repair?




Pictures will help.  Hopefully the reliefs are add ons nailed or glued on.

This is a go away job for most contractors (not enough money for the work involved). Search for appliques at big box stores or online retailers.

Thanks for pointing out that I forgot to post pictures.  Just added them.

That's the "jamb" (frame) and the threshold, both of which are integral parts of the door unit and not just trim details as you seem to imply. I challenge your notion that you don't need new doors. You do.

@isherwood: or you need to be willing to repair things in place rather than replace them. Thresholds can be cut out and replaced, though that may open a small can of worms if the structure supporting the threshold is also damaged.

For me it's less about will and more about cost/benefit. This is obviously a very old door. A repair is a short-term fix, no matter how lovingly executed, and will probably cost half of what a replacement would.

@isherwood - Thank you very much for your perspective!  Looks like I need to do some door shopping then.  Thanks for taking the time to respond.
